# How to sync UI with changes in virtual cart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopping-cart

I am learning some front end design patterns, and I keep reading about how in a shopping cart example, you want to have a virtual shopping cart, and then have the UI listen for changes to it, and then reflect it on the page. But I have not found good examples of exactly how to "listen for changes and reflect it" particularly where I'm essentially syncing changes in multiple places.

Below I took a stab at a most rudimentary system. The code WORKS (fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sqtj2dua/2/)), however, it seems wildly brittle (especially since reality could be far more complex than this with a lot more things to have to match to find the right cart row. The `changePriceInUI` and `removeFromUI` functions, for example, rely on matchers, because I've learned that `item.row` can only reference 1 jQuery object in either Cart page or Total page. That's why the code that's commented out, if used, would only affect the UI on `cart-body` in the `Total page`. But the code that's commented out is what makes most sense to me in terms of most accurately working with items in a cart and syncing changes.

For example, I can imagine item being a `Class` where each time the price is changed, there's a setter function that updates the UI (but again, item.row is only 1 row). But I guess not? Would love to hear how shopping carts are built to sync up changes. Other learning resources welcome!

```
cart = []
cart_body = $(".cart-body")

function addItem(name, price) {
  item = {}
  item.name = name
  item.price = price  
  item.row = $("<tr class='item-row' data-name='"+name+"' data-price='"+price+"'><td class='name'>" + name + "</td><td class='price'>" + price + "</td></tr>")
  cart.push(item)
  addToUI(item.row)
}

function addToUI(item_row) {
  cart_body.append(item_row)
}

function removeItem(name,price) {
  var length = cart.length
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
    if (cart[i].name == name && cart[i].price == price) { 
      item_whose_row_to_remove = cart[i]
      cart.splice(i,1)
      break
    }
  }
  removeFromUI(item_whose_row_to_remove)
}

function removeFromUI(item) {
  // item.row.remove()
  cart_body.find(".item-row[data-name='"+item.name+"'][data-price='"+item.price+"']").remove()
}

function changeItemPrice(name,new_price) {
  var length = cart.length
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
    if (cart[i].name == name) { 
      old_price = cart[i].price
      cart[i].price = new_price
      item_whose_price_to_update = cart[i]
      break
    }
  }
  changePriceInUI(item_whose_price_to_update, old_price)
}

function changePriceInUI(item, old_price) {
  // item.row.find(".price").empty().append(item.price)
  cart_body.find(".item-row[data-name='"+item.name+"'][data-price='"+old_price+"']").find(".price").empty().append(item.price)
}


addItem("Ball", 1)
addItem("Stick",2)
removeItem("Ball",1)
changeItemPrice("Stick",3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one example: https://jsfiddle.net/4tq9a6h3/

I created a `ShoppingCart` class, which owns a reference to a HTML table, as well as an array of shopping cart items. The class handles updating the HTML table internally whenever you call the `addItem`-method to add an item to the cart. The UI can never be out of sync with the `cartItems`-array, since the `cartItems`-array is the "primary source of truth" of which the UI updates are based upon, when the array contents change.

Note that this is missing a lot of optimizations and features. Normally you would not empty the whole HTML table when simply adding a new item for example, because there is no reason to, as the existing table rows will be the same as the existing array elements.

Similarly how the addItem works, you could implement removeItem and changePrice -methods and just call `this.render()` in the end again.

Second note that it is probably not a good idea to code something like this by yourself for production, there are better ways. This example is to answer your question about how you'd virtually decouple data and UI and have the UI updated when the data updates (and how to not rely on HTML elements when you'd like to see what items the user has in cart - you'd just check what the cartItems array contains instead of reading the HTML table rows). The other important thing to takeaway from this is that the **`cartItems`-array is at the center of everything**. Every update to UI is done by **reflecting what the `cartItems`-array contains and never the other way around.**

Furthermore one could probably utilize [Custom Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) for example, in order to trigger the UI updates (calling the render method) after cartItems-array changes and not having to remember calling it "manually".

Requested additions: https://jsfiddle.net/qr0avhwe/2/

Comment: thank you!!! i'm wondering if you have a few minutes, can you extend your example to add the remove or change methods given 1) where the `shoppingcart` UI element is present in 2 places, and 2) you're not re-building the `appendString` from scratch each time (because i see how that would clearly work, but as you say is probably not efficient)? Given the limitation discussed in the Question, I'm frankly not seeing how this resolves the issue of having to look up and make modifications by matching selectors...

Comment: @james I've extended the example and edited my answer (https://jsfiddle.net/4b9uepkd/1/). Render is more optimized now when a new item is added, but going into details regarding how to optimize removing and editing an item is out of the scope (and one of the reasons why I am advicing against implementing this by hand it the first place). I've also added support and example for having the same UI element present in two places, but both sharing the same datasource. One way to to optimize remove/edit would be to detach the HTML list from the DOM first, making the edits and attaching it back.

Comment: Thank you! So can I ask what framework (so it's not built from scratch) would yo use to optimize edit/remove? Or just the question that... IF you are trying to edit/remove from 2 places using 1 datasource, because of the inherent limitations in JS (which again I dunno if there's a framework that addresses), even in your suggestion of detaching, you'd still have to use a selector query to find the UI elements in the 2 places to edit, OR store both of them in an array. Right?

Comment: @james Well, React does this all, but it's not really a "drop it in and go" solution just to solve this. The detaching method... you could use selectors there, they're not the main problem. One thing you could do is to try an key the data as well as the table rows - that way you could directly target your selectors. If you use data-attributes instead of ids, you could also attach back the same elements to all places.

Comment: @james So something like 1) Detach both tables (or table rows) 2) Remove needed objects from the data-array and store the keys that you removed 3) Select the rows from one of the detached tables by using the stored keys and remove those rows 4) Attach the remaining rows back to both tables

Comment: @james As to what libraries can achieve something like this, check out https://github.com/snabbdom/snabbdom or https://maquettejs.org/ or https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom for example. I think the ones you are looking for are called "virtual DOM libraries".